# Передача метода класса в качестве параметра

Tags: функции, классы, boost, c++

Есть два класса

**Connection.h**

```
class Connection {
public:
    void start();
private:
    Connection(io_service& service);
    static void send(Image img);
    static ip::tcp::socket socket_; // необходимо сделать не static.
}
```

**Connection.cpp**

```
Connection::Connection(io_service& service)
    : socket_(service)
{}

void Connection::start() {
    Camera camera = Camera::createCamera();
    camera.start(send);
}

void Connection::send(Image img) {
    write(socket_, buffer(img));
}
```

**Camera.h**

```
typedef boost::function<void()> SendFunc;

class Camera {
public:
    static Camera createCamera();
    void start(SendFunc func);
private:
    Camera();
}
```

**Camera.cpp**

```
Camera::Camera() {}

Camera Camera::createCamera() {
    static Camera camera = Camera();
    return camera;
}

void Camera::start(SendFunc func) {
    Image img = getImage();
    func(img);
}
```

Это работает, но необходимо что бы socket_ в классe Connection не был статичным. Есть еще варианты как можно передать метод класса в качестве параметра?

Comment: Мне кажется, что сильно красивее код сделать не получится. А чем недопустимы статические члены в Вашем случае?

Comment: Если будет создано несколько подключений, то так они все будут работать через один сокет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то пробелема в том, что socket разделяется между всеми камерами и используется для отправки. Если так, то вот одно из решений:

```
class Connection {
public:
    void start();
    void send();

private:
    Connection(io_service& service);
    ip::tcp::socket socket_;
}
```

дальше или в классе камера завести объект Connection, но имхо лучше вообще сделать его свободным.

```
/*где-то в коде*/

Connection c;

Camera c = Camera::createCamera();
c.start( std::bind( &Connection::Send, c ) );
```

В компиляторах до С++11 нет std::bind (если в std::tr1 только), в этом случае использовать boost::bind

**upd:**

В классе `Connection` никакой указатель хранить не нужно, в этом классе есть только сокет и метод `Send`, который, насколько я понимаю, используется для отправки каких-то данных через этот сокет. В нужный момент с помощью `bind` делается функтор (грубо говоря "указатель на функцию") и передаётся классу `Camera`, вызывая который класс `Camera` отсылает данные. Этот функтор нужно сохранить в методе `Start`, иначе как его (функтор) вызывать? Обеъкт `Connection c`, понятно, должен существовать всё время, когда используется отправка данных, это задача программиста проследить за этим.

Comment: т.е. стоит в классе Connection хранить указатель на сам класс?

Comment: У меня объект Connection хранится в shared_ptr. как В таком через boost::bind связать?

Comment: @feelGood: есть 2 варианта

``boost::shared_ptr<Connection> c;``

``boost::bind( &Connection::Send, c, _1 );`` (*1)

``boost::bind( &Connection::Send, c.get(), _1 );`` (*2)

(*1) - в функторе будет копия умного указателя, следовательно будет увеличен счётчик ссылок на объект.

(*2) - в функторе будет "голый" (обычный) указатель, счётчик ссылок увеличен не будет.

В общем случае я лично за второй вариант.

Comment: в обоих случая выдает следующую ошибку
Server.cpp:34:108:   instantiated from here
./boost/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:342:23: error: invalid use of non-static member function
и перед эти еще куча всего, но в комментарий это все не влезет

Comment: Не заметил что у метода Send есть параметр, в таком случае нужно немного изменить bind